# Book/Slides/Videos about points-topology-manifold-charts-riemannian manifolds etc

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, connections

My goal is to study some kind of nonlinear systems through differential geometry. I did an intensive meeting with my supervisor in which he tried to give me an introduction and a link between the following topics:

- Points
- Topology
- Manifolds
- Charts (coordinates)
- Differential manifolds

  - **Riemannian manifolds**

    - Geodesics
    - Exponential maps
    - Logarithmic maps
    - $SO(d)$ case and *hat-map* vs *v-map*
  - **[Connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(mathematics))**

    - [Tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle)
    - Vector fields (flow of a vector field)
    - Christoffel's symbols
    - [Levi-Civita's connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection)
    - Parallel transport
    - Link of the previous with the [Rodrigues' formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula) for rotation

Finally how to arrive from all this to Lie Brackets.

I followed during the meeting but you immediately understand that in 1 hour and a half you can't get all the details of the concepts we touched during the meeting. For this reason I would like to know if you can suggest me some books/slides/videos or whatever to get more understanding of these concepts.

I am going throught the book : [Nonlinear control systems by A.Isidori](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9783540199168).

Someone on this forum suggested to look into the work of John M.Lee: [Introduction to topological Manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441979395), [Introduction to Smooth manifolds](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9982-5)

I found out, reading the Isidori's book that it lacks a bit of graphical explanations which, in this context, I find really useful.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part I used: *An introduction to manifolds - Loring W. Tu* I like it a lot, in my opinion is a very good book with a lot of nice exercises.

For the Riemannian geometry I used the following notes

http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/425/RiemGeom.pdf